# Laravel 5 Validation - error class on form elements

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

My validation form works fine and it looks like this:

```
{!! Form::email('email', null, array('placeholder' => 'Email', 'class' => 'form-control ')) !!}
{{$errors->first('email')}}
```

If the email is not good, I get this error: *The a email has already been taken.*

The thing is that I wan't to put a css class on the input also like `error` in order to add a red background border to the input.

How can I do this?

Comment: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39637788/how-can-i-color-input-fields-border-red-when-i-get-validation-error-laravel-5-3/46314977#46314977) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39637788/how-can-i-color-input-fields-border-red-when-i-get-validation-error-laravel-5-3/46314977#46314977

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was the correct answer for me, without using additional `div's` :

```
{!! Form::email('email', null, $attributes = $errors->has('email') ? array('placeholder' => 'Email', 'class' => 'form-control has-error') : array('placeholder' => 'Email', 'class' => 'form-control')) !!} 
{{$errors->first('email')}}
```

Comment: The problem on this one is Input does not take .has-error class in Bootstrap. This needs to be applied from parent div. Otherwise, this was a good solution.

Comment: i only need to add a class for my input fields to have a red border and this solution worked for me, it is a very long approach though.

Comment: i deleted the `$attributes =` and it worked the same.

Answer (score 8):

> You can use if condition for check errors:

```
 <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error' :'' }}">
   {!! Form::text('email',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Email Address']) !!}
   {!! $errors->first('email','<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use the following code to check if email field has Any validation error

```
 <div class="form-group has-feedback @if($errors->has('email') has-error @endif">
        <input name="email" class="form-control"/>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
        @if ($errors->has('email')) <p class="help-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            {{ $errors->first('email') }}</p>
        @endif
    </div>
```

Comment: useful answer for when you're trying to implement into a theme / styled form. Take note of the syntax error though in the first div class; if statement bracket ) is missing

Answer (score 1):

You could just add HTML around it and style it however you want.

HTML:

```
<span class="error">{{$errors->first('email')}}</span>
```

CSS:

```
.error {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Edit: Add the `has-error` class to the input itself like this:

```
{!! Form::email('email', null, array('placeholder' => 'Email', 'class' => 'form-control ' . $errors->first('email', 'has-error'))) !!}
```

Comment: I don't need a new element created. I need a css class added to my email input.

Comment: There's a very simple solution to that. :) Check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Add custom error message

```
'custom' => array(
    'email' => array(
        'required' => 'We need to know your e-mail address!',
    ),
),
```

[Custom Error Messages in Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-error-messages)

Comment: I dont need a custom error message. I need a css class added to my input.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> 
  if({{$errors->has('email')}}){
    $(input[type="email"]).css('border-color', 'red');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

add class has-error to your form like this

```
{!! Form::email('email', null, array('placeholder' => 'Email', 'class' => 'form-control has-error')) !!}
```

you can use if condition if there's an error, set the class in

```
@if($errors->has('email'))
    {!! Form::email('email', null, array('placeholder' => 'Email', 'class' => 'form-control has-error')) !!}
@else
    {!! Form::email('email', null, array('placeholder' => 'Email', 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}
@endif
```

or you can do like this

```
<input class="form-control {{ $errors->has('email') ? 'has-error' : '' }}" name="email" placeholder="Email">
```

Comment: That class should appear only if the form validation failed, not always as you sugested.