# How can I color input fields border red when I get validation error laravel 5.3

Tags: validation, laravel-5.3

My Validation Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   // dd($request->all());

    /////Validations////

    $this->Validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|min:3|',
        'email' => 'required|unique:customers' ,
        'favorite' => 'required',
        'Password' => 'required|min:6',
        'Confirm_Password' => 'required|same:Password',
        ]);

    $user = new customer;
    $user ->name=input::get("name");
    $user ->email=input::get("email");
    $user ->country=input::get("country");
    $user ->gender=input::get("gender");
    $user ->favorite=implode(" , " , input::get("favorite"));

    if(input::hasfile("image")){
        $files = Input::file('image');
        $name = time()."_". $files->getClientOriginalName();
        $image = $files->move(public_path().'/image' , $name);
        $user->image=$name;
    }

    $user ->psw=input::get("psw");

    $user->save();
    return redirect("showall");
}
```

Insert.blade.php

```
<form action="store" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <ul><span style="color:red;">{!! $errors->first('name') !!}</span></ul>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{old('name')}}" id="name" autofill="off">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
<ul><span style="color:red;">{!! $errors->first('email') !!}</span></ul>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="{{old('email')}}" id="email" autofill="off">
<br>
<br>
 Country&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name="country" id="country">
 <option value="USA">USA </option>
 <option value="ENGLAND">ENGLAND </option>
 <option value="JAPAN">JAPAN </option>
 <option value="ITALY">ITALY</option>
 </select>
  <br>
  <br>
    Gender&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
<br>
    <br>
    <ul><span style="color:red;">{!! $errors->first('favorite') !!}</span></ul>
    <input type="checkbox" name="favorite[]" value="sout">South
    <input type="checkbox" name="favorite[]" value="north">North
    <input type="checkbox" name="favorite[]" value="east">East
    <input type="checkbox" name="favorite[]" value="west">West
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="file" name="image">
<br>
    <br>
    <ul><span style="color:red;">{!! $errors->first('Confirm_Password') !!}</span></ul>
    <label for="email">Password</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="password" name="Password" value="" id="Password">
<ul><span style="color:red;">{!! $errors->first('Confirm_Password') !!}</span></ul>
    <label for="email">Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="Password" name="Confirm_Password" value="" id="cpsw">
    <br>
    <br>
<label for="submit"></label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
 </form>
```

Form where I want to change fields color:

[image: Form where I want to change fields color]

I want to change input fields border color to change red when I get a validation error.
I try my best but I don't know how to rid off this problem.

Answer (score 7):

**Add this CSS code first:**

```
.form-error {

  border: 2px solid #e74c3c;
}
```

**And HTML Code is ::**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control{{($errors->first('name') ? " form-error" : "")}}" name="name" placeholder="Name">
```

**if you need error message below the input field then ::**

```
    <input class="form-control" required="required" name="name" type="text" id="name">
    {!! $errors->first('name', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
```

Comment: can you update your solution to show how it would work with Tailwind invalid: ?